# Push value to a webform input textbox using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have created a search using Angular JS where I am pulling data from a JSON file and display it in a table on a page which is working fine. The table row and table column are created by Angular ng-repeat.

And there is a webform added below the table which has few fields (this is simple html/css/js webform). I want that once the table row is clicked, the data from table columns and push it in the webform input text box. What I have tried is ng-click="callfunction(pass values) and in the callfunction I can display all the values passed in console of the web browser but I am not able to find how to push the values in the text box of webform, can someone please help. Running sample can be found at [here](http://allhandsregistration.businesscatalyst.com/angularajax)

Answer (score 0):

Just checked and issue was with the IDs I was targetting. Silly me, the IDs for the webform text box were camel cased and I was targeting all lower case. Anyways thank you guys for being there.

Comment: I've posted answer which binds your webform in angular way

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your model in controller which you want to bind with view :

```
$scope.firstname = '';
$scope.lastname='';
$scope.email = '';
```

Now, you should bind your model to your view :

```
 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="FirstName">First Name <span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" name="FirstName" ng-model="firstname" id="FirstName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="LastName">Last Name <span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" name="LastName" ng-model="lastname" id="LastName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="EmailAddress">Email Address <span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" name="EmailAddress" ng-model="email" id="EmailAddress" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /> </td>
```

Finally, you should update your model by using your click method in each row :

```
 $scope.pushval = function (first,last,email)
        {
             $scope.firstname = first;
             $scope.lastname = last
             $scope.email = email;

        }
```

I want to suggest you one ng-click method : 
Your ng-click should be :

```
pushval(i) //it's good to pass object and get property value from object in controller
```

And your `pushval` method would be like :

```
$scope.pushval = function (myRow)
        {
             $scope.firstname = myRow.firstName;
             $scope.lastname = myRow.lastName;
             $scope.email = myRow.email1.value;

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on this Akash KC.